# Abp.io angular project. Swagger page loads, but all calls return 500 internal server error

Tags: azure-web-app-service, abp

I created an angular abp.io application. I mainly followed step for a blazor app in this tutorial. [see tut](https://abpioazuredevopsblazor.azurewebsites.net/). The db and api are hosted on azure. Everything runs correctly locally. The remote database is updated.

There are no CORS errors.

The logs.txt shows only successes since the last restart. (bottom)

The swagger page loads. However if I 'Try IT'/'Execute' any endpoint such as '{domain}.api/app/monitoring/series-one' which should just return a list of numbers... I receive '500 - Internal Server Error'.

```
2021-09-10 19:03:30.579 +00:00 [INF] Starting Vhb.AtlasAdmin.HttpApi.Host.
2021-09-10 19:03:36.216 +00:00 [INF] Azure Web Sites environment detected. Using 'C:\home\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys' as key repository; keys will not be encrypted at rest.
2021-09-10 19:03:36.427 +00:00 [INF] Loaded ABP modules:
2021-09-10 19:03:36.427 +00:00 [INF] - Vhb.AtlasAdmin.AtlasAdminHttpApiHostModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.427 +00:00 [INF]   - Vhb.AtlasAdmin.AtlasAdminHttpApiModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.427 +00:00 [INF]     - Vhb.AtlasAdmin.AtlasAdminApplicationContractsModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.427 +00:00 [INF]       - Vhb.AtlasAdmin.AtlasAdminDomainSharedModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.427 +00:00 [INF]         - Volo.Abp.AuditLogging.AbpAuditLoggingDomainSharedModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.427 +00:00 [INF]         - Volo.Abp.BackgroundJobs.AbpBackgroundJobsDomainSharedModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.427 +00:00 [INF]         - Volo.Abp.FeatureManagement.AbpFeatureManagementDomainSharedModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.427 +00:00 [INF]           - Volo.Abp.Validation.AbpValidationModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.427 +00:00 [INF]             - Volo.Abp.Validation.AbpValidationAbstractionsModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.427 +00:00 [INF]             - Volo.Abp.Localization.AbpLocalizationModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.427 +00:00 [INF]               - Volo.Abp.VirtualFileSystem.AbpVirtualFileSystemModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.427 +00:00 [INF]               - Volo.Abp.Settings.AbpSettingsModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.427 +00:00 [INF]                 - Volo.Abp.Localization.AbpLocalizationAbstractionsModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.427 +00:00 [INF]                 - Volo.Abp.Security.AbpSecurityModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.427 +00:00 [INF]                 - Volo.Abp.MultiTenancy.AbpMultiTenancyModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.427 +00:00 [INF]                   - Volo.Abp.Data.AbpDataModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.427 +00:00 [INF]                     - Volo.Abp.ObjectExtending.AbpObjectExtendingModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.427 +00:00 [INF]                     - Volo.Abp.Uow.AbpUnitOfWorkModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.427 +00:00 [INF]                     - Volo.Abp.EventBus.Abstractions.AbpEventBusAbstractionsModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.427 +00:00 [INF]         - Volo.Abp.Identity.AbpIdentityDomainSharedModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.428 +00:00 [INF]           - Volo.Abp.Users.AbpUsersDomainSharedModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.428 +00:00 [INF]           - Volo.Abp.Features.AbpFeaturesModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.428 +00:00 [INF]             - Volo.Abp.Authorization.AbpAuthorizationAbstractionsModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.428 +00:00 [INF]         - Volo.Abp.IdentityServer.AbpIdentityServerDomainSharedModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.428 +00:00 [INF]         - Volo.Abp.PermissionManagement.AbpPermissionManagementDomainSharedModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.428 +00:00 [INF]         - Volo.Abp.SettingManagement.AbpSettingManagementDomainSharedModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.428 +00:00 [INF]         - Volo.Abp.TenantManagement.AbpTenantManagementDomainSharedModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.428 +00:00 [INF]       - Volo.Abp.Account.AbpAccountApplicationContractsModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.428 +00:00 [INF]         - Volo.Abp.Identity.AbpIdentityApplicationContractsModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.428 +00:00 [INF]           - Volo.Abp.Users.AbpUsersAbstractionModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.428 +00:00 [INF]             - Volo.Abp.EventBus.AbpEventBusModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.428 +00:00 [INF]               - Volo.Abp.Json.AbpJsonModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.428 +00:00 [INF]                 - Volo.Abp.Timing.AbpTimingModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.428 +00:00 [INF]           - Volo.Abp.Authorization.AbpAuthorizationModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.428 +00:00 [INF]           - Volo.Abp.PermissionManagement.AbpPermissionManagementApplicationContractsModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.428 +00:00 [INF]             - Volo.Abp.Application.AbpDddApplicationContractsModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.428 +00:00 [INF]               - Volo.Abp.Auditing.AbpAuditingModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.428 +00:00 [INF]                 - Volo.Abp.Threading.AbpThreadingModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.428 +00:00 [INF]       - Volo.Abp.FeatureManagement.AbpFeatureManagementApplicationContractsModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.428 +00:00 [INF]       - Volo.Abp.SettingManagement.AbpSettingManagementApplicationContractsModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.428 +00:00 [INF]       - Volo.Abp.TenantManagement.AbpTenantManagementApplicationContractsModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.428 +00:00 [INF]     - Volo.Abp.Account.AbpAccountHttpApiModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.428 +00:00 [INF]       - Volo.Abp.Identity.AbpIdentityHttpApiModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.428 +00:00 [INF]         - Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc.AbpAspNetCoreMvcModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.428 +00:00 [INF]           - Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.AbpAspNetCoreModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.428 +00:00 [INF]             - Volo.Abp.Http.AbpHttpModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.428 +00:00 [INF]               - Volo.Abp.Http.AbpHttpAbstractionsModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.428 +00:00 [INF]               - Volo.Abp.Minify.AbpMinifyModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.428 +00:00 [INF]             - Volo.Abp.ExceptionHandling.AbpExceptionHandlingModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.428 +00:00 [INF]           - Volo.Abp.ApiVersioning.AbpApiVersioningAbstractionsModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.428 +00:00 [INF]           - Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc.AbpAspNetCoreMvcContractsModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.428 +00:00 [INF]           - Volo.Abp.UI.Navigation.AbpUiNavigationModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.428 +00:00 [INF]             - Volo.Abp.UI.AbpUiModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.428 +00:00 [INF]           - Volo.Abp.GlobalFeatures.AbpGlobalFeaturesModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.428 +00:00 [INF]           - Volo.Abp.Application.AbpDddApplicationModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.428 +00:00 [INF]             - Volo.Abp.Domain.AbpDddDomainModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.428 +00:00 [INF]               - Volo.Abp.Guids.AbpGuidsModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.428 +00:00 [INF]               - Volo.Abp.ObjectMapping.AbpObjectMappingModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.428 +00:00 [INF]               - Volo.Abp.Specifications.AbpSpecificationsModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.428 +00:00 [INF]     - Volo.Abp.PermissionManagement.HttpApi.AbpPermissionManagementHttpApiModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.428 +00:00 [INF]     - Volo.Abp.TenantManagement.AbpTenantManagementHttpApiModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.428 +00:00 [INF]       - Volo.Abp.FeatureManagement.AbpFeatureManagementHttpApiModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.428 +00:00 [INF]     - Volo.Abp.SettingManagement.AbpSettingManagementHttpApiModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.428 +00:00 [INF]   - Volo.Abp.Autofac.AbpAutofacModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.428 +00:00 [INF]     - Volo.Abp.Castle.AbpCastleCoreModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.428 +00:00 [INF]   - Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.MultiTenancy.AbpAspNetCoreMultiTenancyModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.428 +00:00 [INF]   - Vhb.AtlasAdmin.AtlasAdminApplicationModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.428 +00:00 [INF]     - Vhb.AtlasAdmin.AtlasAdminDomainModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.428 +00:00 [INF]       - Volo.Abp.AuditLogging.AbpAuditLoggingDomainModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.428 +00:00 [INF]       - Volo.Abp.BackgroundJobs.AbpBackgroundJobsDomainModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.428 +00:00 [INF]         - Volo.Abp.BackgroundJobs.AbpBackgroundJobsModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.428 +00:00 [INF]           - Volo.Abp.BackgroundJobs.AbpBackgroundJobsAbstractionsModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.428 +00:00 [INF]           - Volo.Abp.BackgroundWorkers.AbpBackgroundWorkersModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.428 +00:00 [INF]         - Volo.Abp.AutoMapper.AbpAutoMapperModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.428 +00:00 [INF]       - Volo.Abp.FeatureManagement.AbpFeatureManagementDomainModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.428 +00:00 [INF]         - Volo.Abp.Caching.AbpCachingModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.428 +00:00 [INF]           - Volo.Abp.Serialization.AbpSerializationModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.428 +00:00 [INF]       - Volo.Abp.Identity.AbpIdentityDomainModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.428 +00:00 [INF]         - Volo.Abp.Users.AbpUsersDomainModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.428 +00:00 [INF]       - Volo.Abp.PermissionManagement.Identity.AbpPermissionManagementDomainIdentityModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.428 +00:00 [INF]         - Volo.Abp.PermissionManagement.AbpPermissionManagementDomainModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.428 +00:00 [INF]       - Volo.Abp.IdentityServer.AbpIdentityServerDomainModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.428 +00:00 [INF]       - Volo.Abp.PermissionManagement.IdentityServer.AbpPermissionManagementDomainIdentityServerModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.428 +00:00 [INF]       - Volo.Abp.SettingManagement.AbpSettingManagementDomainModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.428 +00:00 [INF]       - Volo.Abp.TenantManagement.AbpTenantManagementDomainModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.428 +00:00 [INF]       - Volo.Abp.Emailing.AbpEmailingModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.428 +00:00 [INF]         - Volo.Abp.TextTemplating.AbpTextTemplatingModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.428 +00:00 [INF]           - Volo.Abp.TextTemplating.Scriban.AbpTextTemplatingScribanModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.428 +00:00 [INF]             - Volo.Abp.TextTemplating.AbpTextTemplatingCoreModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.428 +00:00 [INF]     - Volo.Abp.Account.AbpAccountApplicationModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.428 +00:00 [INF]       - Volo.Abp.Identity.AbpIdentityApplicationModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.428 +00:00 [INF]         - Volo.Abp.PermissionManagement.AbpPermissionManagementApplicationModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.428 +00:00 [INF]     - Volo.Abp.TenantManagement.AbpTenantManagementApplicationModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.428 +00:00 [INF]     - Volo.Abp.FeatureManagement.AbpFeatureManagementApplicationModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.428 +00:00 [INF]     - Volo.Abp.SettingManagement.AbpSettingManagementApplicationModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.428 +00:00 [INF]   - Vhb.AtlasAdmin.EntityFrameworkCore.AtlasAdminEntityFrameworkCoreModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.428 +00:00 [INF]     - Volo.Abp.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.AbpIdentityEntityFrameworkCoreModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.428 +00:00 [INF]       - Volo.Abp.Users.EntityFrameworkCore.AbpUsersEntityFrameworkCoreModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.428 +00:00 [INF]         - Volo.Abp.EntityFrameworkCore.AbpEntityFrameworkCoreModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.428 +00:00 [INF]     - Volo.Abp.IdentityServer.EntityFrameworkCore.AbpIdentityServerEntityFrameworkCoreModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.428 +00:00 [INF]     - Volo.Abp.PermissionManagement.EntityFrameworkCore.AbpPermissionManagementEntityFrameworkCoreModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.428 +00:00 [INF]     - Volo.Abp.SettingManagement.EntityFrameworkCore.AbpSettingManagementEntityFrameworkCoreModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.428 +00:00 [INF]     - Volo.Abp.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.AbpEntityFrameworkCoreSqlServerModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.428 +00:00 [INF]     - Volo.Abp.BackgroundJobs.EntityFrameworkCore.AbpBackgroundJobsEntityFrameworkCoreModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.428 +00:00 [INF]     - Volo.Abp.AuditLogging.EntityFrameworkCore.AbpAuditLoggingEntityFrameworkCoreModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.428 +00:00 [INF]     - Volo.Abp.TenantManagement.EntityFrameworkCore.AbpTenantManagementEntityFrameworkCoreModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.428 +00:00 [INF]     - Volo.Abp.FeatureManagement.EntityFrameworkCore.AbpFeatureManagementEntityFrameworkCoreModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.428 +00:00 [INF]   - Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc.UI.Theme.Basic.AbpAspNetCoreMvcUiBasicThemeModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.428 +00:00 [INF]     - Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc.UI.Theme.Shared.AbpAspNetCoreMvcUiThemeSharedModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.428 +00:00 [INF]       - Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc.UI.Bootstrap.AbpAspNetCoreMvcUiBootstrapModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.428 +00:00 [INF]         - Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc.UI.AbpAspNetCoreMvcUiModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.428 +00:00 [INF]       - Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc.UI.Packages.AbpAspNetCoreMvcUiPackagesModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.428 +00:00 [INF]         - Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc.UI.Bundling.AbpAspNetCoreMvcUiBundlingAbstractionsModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.428 +00:00 [INF]       - Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc.UI.Widgets.AbpAspNetCoreMvcUiWidgetsModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.428 +00:00 [INF]         - Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc.UI.Bundling.AbpAspNetCoreMvcUiBundlingModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.428 +00:00 [INF]     - Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc.UI.MultiTenancy.AbpAspNetCoreMvcUiMultiTenancyModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.428 +00:00 [INF]   - Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.AbpAspNetCoreAuthenticationJwtBearerModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.428 +00:00 [INF]   - Volo.Abp.Account.Web.AbpAccountWebIdentityServerModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.428 +00:00 [INF]     - Volo.Abp.Account.Web.AbpAccountWebModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.428 +00:00 [INF]       - Volo.Abp.Identity.AspNetCore.AbpIdentityAspNetCoreModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.428 +00:00 [INF]   - Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Serilog.AbpAspNetCoreSerilogModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.428 +00:00 [INF]   - Volo.Abp.Swashbuckle.AbpSwashbuckleModule
2021-09-10 19:03:36.624 +00:00 [DBG] Started background worker: Volo.Abp.BackgroundJobs.BackgroundJobWorker
2021-09-10 19:03:36.632 +00:00 [DBG] Started background worker: Volo.Abp.IdentityServer.Tokens.TokenCleanupBackgroundWorker
2021-09-10 19:03:36.652 +00:00 [INF] Starting IdentityServer4 version 4.1.1+cebd52f5bc61bdefc262fd20739d4d087c6f961f
2021-09-10 19:03:38.645 +00:00 [INF] Using the default authentication scheme Identity.Application for IdentityServer
2021-09-10 19:03:38.645 +00:00 [DBG] Using Identity.Application as default ASP.NET Core scheme for authentication
2021-09-10 19:03:38.645 +00:00 [DBG] Using Identity.External as default ASP.NET Core scheme for sign-in
2021-09-10 19:03:38.645 +00:00 [DBG] Using Identity.External as default ASP.NET Core scheme for sign-out
2021-09-10 19:03:38.645 +00:00 [DBG] Using Identity.Application as default ASP.NET Core scheme for challenge
2021-09-10 19:03:38.645 +00:00 [DBG] Using Identity.Application as default ASP.NET Core scheme for forbid
2021-09-10 19:03:39.668 +00:00 [INF] Initialized all ABP modules.
2021-09-10 19:03:39.806 +00:00 [INF] Now listening on: http://127.0.0.1:30125
2021-09-10 19:03:39.806 +00:00 [INF] Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
2021-09-10 19:03:39.806 +00:00 [INF] Hosting environment: Staging
2021-09-10 19:03:39.806 +00:00 [INF] Content root path: C:\home\site\wwwroot
2021-09-10 19:03:39.956 +00:00 [INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://vhbatlasadmin2.azurewebsites.net/.well-known/openid-configuration - -
2021-09-10 19:03:44.407 +00:00 [INF] CORS policy execution successful.
2021-09-10 19:03:44.497 +00:00 [DBG] Login Url: /Account/Login
2021-09-10 19:03:44.497 +00:00 [DBG] Login Return Url Parameter: ReturnUrl
2021-09-10 19:03:44.497 +00:00 [DBG] Logout Url: /Account/Logout
2021-09-10 19:03:44.497 +00:00 [DBG] ConsentUrl Url: /Consent
2021-09-10 19:03:44.497 +00:00 [DBG] Consent Return Url Parameter: returnUrl
2021-09-10 19:03:44.497 +00:00 [DBG] Error Url: /Account/Error
2021-09-10 19:03:44.497 +00:00 [DBG] Error Id Parameter: errorId
2021-09-10 19:03:44.813 +00:00 [DBG] CORS request made for path: /.well-known/openid-configuration from origin: https://vhbatlasadminangular.azurewebsites.net
2021-09-10 19:03:45.612 +00:00 [DBG] CorsPolicyService allowed origin: https://vhbatlasadminangular.azurewebsites.net
2021-09-10 19:03:45.613 +00:00 [INF] CORS policy execution successful.
2021-09-10 19:03:45.634 +00:00 [DBG] Request path /.well-known/openid-configuration matched to endpoint type Discovery
2021-09-10 19:03:46.688 +00:00 [DBG] Endpoint enabled: Discovery, successfully created handler: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.DiscoveryEndpoint
2021-09-10 19:03:46.688 +00:00 [INF] Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.DiscoveryEndpoint for /.well-known/openid-configuration
2021-09-10 19:03:46.693 +00:00 [DBG] Start discovery request
2021-09-10 19:03:48.394 +00:00 [INF] Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET http://vhbatlasadmin2.azurewebsites.net/.well-known/openid-configuration - - - 200 - application/json;+charset=UTF-8 8437.7977ms
2021-09-10 19:03:48.487 +00:00 [INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://vhbatlasadmin2.azurewebsites.net/.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks - -
2021-09-10 19:03:48.495 +00:00 [INF] CORS policy execution successful.
2021-09-10 19:03:48.504 +00:00 [DBG] CORS request made for path: /.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks from origin: https://vhbatlasadminangular.azurewebsites.net
2021-09-10 19:03:48.507 +00:00 [DBG] CorsPolicyService allowed origin: https://vhbatlasadminangular.azurewebsites.net
2021-09-10 19:03:48.507 +00:00 [INF] CORS policy execution successful.
2021-09-10 19:03:48.513 +00:00 [DBG] Request path /.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks matched to endpoint type Discovery
2021-09-10 19:03:48.524 +00:00 [DBG] Endpoint enabled: Discovery, successfully created handler: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.DiscoveryKeyEndpoint
2021-09-10 19:03:48.524 +00:00 [INF] Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.DiscoveryKeyEndpoint for /.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks
2021-09-10 19:03:48.525 +00:00 [DBG] Start key discovery request
2021-09-10 19:03:48.557 +00:00 [INF] Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET http://vhbatlasadmin2.azurewebsites.net/.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks - - - 200 - application/json;+charset=UTF-8 69.7467ms
```

Answer (score 2):

This error was not related to the back-end code.

The azure app service configuration had a virtual-app/path-map that conflicted with the route. After removing this path-map the routes were able to respond correctly.